# Why doesn't Python run my bash code?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, unit-testing

I'm trying to debug some unit tests that have been provided for testing an integration.

I'm sure this worked last time I tested it on my local machine, but that seems to have changed - the file hasn't been altered, so I don't know what's changed since then.

I have stripped out the identifying comments and changed some names from the original unit tests because it's proprietary software.

The syntax error is:

```
  File "unitTests.sh", line 39
    gLastFullPath=`python -c "import os; print os.path.realpath('${1}')"`
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The full script is here:

```
#!/bin/bash

# If non-zero, then run in debug mode, outputting debug information
debug=0

# Set the following to 1 to force an error for testing purposes
forceError=0

separator="===================================================================================================="

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Convert the specified path to a full path and return it in the gLastFullPath
# global variable.
#
# Input params:
#   $1  - Path to convert to full
#
# Output params:
#   $gLastFullPath  -   Set to the converted full path
gLastFullPath=""
getFullPath()
{
    # Use Python (because it's easier than Bash) to convert the passed path to
    # a full path.
    gLastFullPath=`python -c "import os; print os.path.realpath('${1}')"`
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fatalError()
{
    echo "${separator}"
    echo "Fatal Error: $1"
    echo "${separator}"
    exit 1
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# If a file or folder exists at the specified path, then delete it. If it's a
# directory, then its entire contents is deleted.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
deleteIfExists()
{
    if [[ 0 -ne $debug ]]; then
        echo "deleteIfExists called..."
    fi

    if [[ -e "$1" ]]; then
        # If it's a directory, then make sure it contains no locked files
        if [[ -d "$1" ]]; then
            chflags -R nouchg "$1"
        fi

        if [[ 0 -ne $debug ]]; then
            echo "  Deleting the existing file or directory:"
            echo "    $1"
        fi

        # Do the remove and check for an error.
        /bin/rm -rf "$1"
        if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
            fatalError "Unable to delete $1."
        fi
    fi

    if [[ 0 -ne $debug ]]; then
        echo
    fi
}


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Script starts here
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Get the full path to this script
scriptPath=`which "$0"`
getFullPath "${scriptPath}"
scriptFullPath="${gLastFullPath}"
scriptDir=`dirname "${scriptFullPath}"`
scriptName=`basename "${scriptFullPath}"`

if [[ 0 -ne $debug ]]; then
    echo "$scriptName: Debug tracing is on."
    echo
fi

# Get the SDK project root path
getFullPath "${scriptDir}/.."
projRoot="${gLastFullPath}"

# Get the top of the server tree
getFullPath "${projRoot}/SUBSYS_TOP"
subsysTop="${gLastFullPath}"

libPythonBase="${projRoot}/src/lib/py/devilsoftPy"
devilsoftPython="${libPythonBase}/devilsoftpy"

if [[ 0 -ne $debug ]]; then
    echo "$scriptName: Project root dir:     \"${projRoot}\""
    echo "$scriptName: SUBSYS_TOP:           \"${subsysTop}\""
    echo "$scriptName: Lib python base:      \"${libPythonBase}\""
    echo "$scriptName: devilsoft python:    \"${devilsoftPython}\""
    echo
fi

# First we have to launch the test python server. This is used by some of the other client tests to 
# run against.
testServer="${devilsoftPython}/test/TestServer.py"
if [[ ! -f "${testServer}" ]]; then
    fatalError "Could not find the expected test server: \"${testServer}\""
fi

# Carve out a place for our test server log file
tempFolder="/tmp/devilsoft"
mkdir -p "${tempFolder}"
testServerLogFile="${tempFolder}/TestServer.log"

echo "Starting the test server: \"${testServer}\""
echo "  Logging to this file:   \"${testServerLogFile}\""
export PYTHONPATH="${libPythonBase}:${PYTHONPATH}"; "${testServer}" > "${testServerLogFile}" 2>&1 &
testServerPid=$!
echo "  Server started with pid ${testServerPid}..."
echo

echo "  Taking a little snooze to let the test server initialize..."
sleep 2

# If we're forcing errors for testing, then kill the test server. This will cause downstream scripts
# to fail because there will be no server to talk to.
if [[ $forceError -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Forcing downstream errors by killing the test server..."
    kill ${testServerPid}
    wait ${testServerPid}
    testServerPid=0
    echo
fi

testResultsLogFile="${tempFolder}/TestResults.log"
echo "Testing each python script in the library..."
echo "  Test results will be written to this log file: \"${testResultsLogFile}\""
echo
deleteIfExists "${testResultsLogFile}"

# Save and set the field separator so that we can handle spaces in paths
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

failedScripts=()
lastError=0
pythonSources=($(find "${devilsoftPython}" -name '*.py'  ! -name '*.svn*' ! -name '__init__.py' ! -name 'TestServer.py' ! -name 'ServerClient.py'))
for pythonSourceFile in ${pythonSources[*]}; do
    echo "  Testing python source \"${pythonSourceFile}\""
    export PYTHONPATH="${libPythonBase}:${PYTHONPATH}"; "${pythonSourceFile}" >> "${testResultsLogFile}" 2>&1
    result=$?
    if [[ $result -ne 0 ]]; then
        pythonSourceName=`basename "${pythonSourceFile}"`
        echo "    Error ${result} returned from the above script ${pythonSourceName}!"
        lastError=${result}
        failedScripts+=("${pythonSourceFile}")
    fi
done
echo

# Restore the original field separator
IFS=$SAVEIFS

if [[ ${testServerPid} -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Telling the test server to quit..."
    kill ${testServerPid}
    wait ${testServerPid}
    echo
fi

# If we got an error, tell the user
if [[ $lastError -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "IMPORTANT! The following scripts failed with errors:"
    for failedScript in "${failedScripts[@]}"; do
       echo "  \"${failedScript}\""
    done
    echo

    fatalError "Review the log files to figure out why the above scripts failed."
fi

echo "${separator}"
echo " Hurray! All tests passed!"
echo "${separator}"
echo

exit 0
```

This is all being run in Python 2.7

Comment: This doesn't look like Python code to me. Python doesn't use curly brackets to surround a function body. The first line says `#!/bin/bash`. Are you sure this isn't a bash script?

Comment: Here's what I suspect: OP is getting a Python error because he's trying to run this file using the Python interpreter. When he says "I'm sure this worked last time I tested it on my local machine", it's because the last time he tested it, he ran it in bash.

Comment: Ahh yes: it so happens that all the statements before it are also correct Python! Funny.

Comment: Expected better from Yoda, I did.

Comment: GNU coreutils provides the command `realpath`, so you don't need to start Python just for that.

Comment: As others pointed out, the answer to "Why doesn't Python run my bash code?" is that Python cannot run Bash code. Python can only run proper Python code. The script presented in the question should be run with Bash instead.

Comment: So as it turns out, I'm an idiot who was too tired and stressed to notice I was trying to run a shell script in Python. Thanks for the assist! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bash script, not a Python script.  Run it using `./script_name.sh` or `bash script_name.sh` instead of `python script_name.sh`.

Comment: So as it turns out, I'm an idiot who was too tired and stressed to notice I was trying to run a shell script in Python. Thanks for the assist! ;)